# Jenkins fails build but on local machine everething is ok

Tags: jenkins, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

[INFO] Fork Value is true

[java] The following errors occurred during analysis:

[java] Aug 09, 2013 3:16:04 PM edu.umd.cs.findbugs.TextUIBugReporter reportAnalysisError

[java] SEVERE: Unable to get XClass for java/lang/StringBuilder

...

After these messages Jenkins ends build with failure. On local machine i got these messages too, but nothing interrupts, and findbugs, pmd and checkstyle finish correctly.

Also on Jenkins i got

[PMD] No report found for mojo check

[FINDBUGS] No report found for mojo check

, but on local machine i don't. Seems like these two stranges are linked, how can i fix them?

I run mvn verify.
SCA included in pom.xml in build section like

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>findbugs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in different jdks. On local machine i have 1.7, but on Jenkins - 1.8, so i simply changed version. And seems like roots of this bug are in jdk 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

apparently, the class structure changed in Java 8. Therefore, FindBugs version 2.0.3 (latest release as of 1. Mai 2014) and earlier fail on classes compiled on JDK 1.8 (or later). They already fixed this in the FindBugs development version (not released as of 4. May 2014). The latest maven plugin (findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.3) uses FindBugs 2.0.2.

I decided to generate the maven reports with Java 7, until the fix (and a new FindBugs maven plugin version using it) is released.

to generate the reports with Java 7 (linux):

```
JAVA_HOME=${HOME}/Software/jdk1.7 mvn site
```

related FindBugs bug reports:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1271/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1264/